# ActionScript3: What code should I use to stop the player controlled sprite from moving?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, flash

I'm very new to ActionScript3 and am making an asteroids-type game. Right now, the ship continues floating in a straight line when you let go of the movement buttons, and I want to be able to stop that from happening. I'm thinking either a dedicated button for braking, like the b key, or if the keys are not pressed to stop movement, whichever would be easier. Like I said I'm really new to AS3 so not even sure what part of my code is making them keep flying in a straight line. Here is the code to control movement for reference:

```
// register key presses
        public function keyDownFunction(event:KeyboardEvent) {
            if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                    leftArrow = true;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                    rightArrow = true;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                    upArrow = true;
            //Add event listener for down arrow
            } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                    downArrow = true;
                    // show thruster
                    if (gameMode == "play") ship.gotoAndStop(2);
            } else if (event.keyCode == 32) { // space
                    var channel:SoundChannel = shootSound.play();
                    newMissile();
            } else if (event.keyCode == 90) { // z
                    startShield(false);
                    var channel:SoundChannel = shieldSound.play();
            }
        }

        // register key ups
        public function keyUpFunction(event:KeyboardEvent) {
            if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                leftArrow = false;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                rightArrow = false;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                upArrow = false;
            //Add listener for down arrow
            } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                downArrow = false;
                // remove thruster
                if (gameMode == "play") ship.gotoAndStop(1);
            }
        }

        // animate ship
        public function moveShip(timeDiff:uint) {

            // rotate and thrust
            if (leftArrow) {
                ship.rotation -= shipRotationSpeed*timeDiff;
            } else if (rightArrow) {
                ship.rotation += shipRotationSpeed*timeDiff;
            } else if (upArrow) {
                shipMoveX += Math.cos(Math.PI*ship.rotation/180)*thrustPower;
                shipMoveY += Math.sin(Math.PI*ship.rotation/180)*thrustPower;
                //Added down arrow movement to allow player to move backwards
            } else if (downArrow) {
                shipMoveX -= Math.cos(Math.PI*ship.rotation/180)*thrustPower;
                shipMoveY -= Math.sin(Math.PI*ship.rotation/180)*thrustPower;
            }

            // move
            ship.x += shipMoveX;
            ship.y += shipMoveY;
```

Comment: If it is your code, how is that you not sure which part does what, even if you are new to AS3?

Comment: Well I have the movement down as you can see but I'm not sure what in AS3 is keeping it moving in a straight line after letting go of the key. I have event listeners for key up and key down, so it should stop when the keys aren't being pressed. Thank you anyways for the non helpful comment.

Comment: From what I can see, it's not the code: you ultimately have a logic problem. "shipMoveX" never gets reset; it keeps whatever value it had even when keys are released, thus keeping your ship moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that there is a little logic problem in your code. Your ship will move on 'til
judgement day because the two variables responsible for the speed of it's motion - shipMoveX
and shipMoveY - aren't automatically degraded over time.

Now there are literally thousands of ways of how this could be achieved but let's keep things
simple.
You are using a class variable called **thrustPower** - make sure to set it to *0.1* and that the value of both **shipMoveX** & **shipMoveY** is *0*.
Additionally add these class variables:

```
private var thrustHorizontal:Number = 0;
private var thrustVertical:Number = 0;
private var speed:Number = 0;
private var maxSpeed:Number = 5;
private var decay:Number = 0.97;
```

Replace the moveShip function with this:

```
public function moveShip(timeDiff:uint):void
{

    thrustHorizontal = Math.sin(Math.PI * ship.rotation / 180);
    thrustVertical = Math.cos(Math.PI * ship.rotation / 180);
    // rotate and thrust
    if (leftArrow)
    {
        ship.rotation -= shipRotationSpeed * timeDiff;
    }
    else if (rightArrow)
    {
        ship.rotation += shipRotationSpeed * timeDiff;
    }
    else if (upArrow)
    {
        shipMoveX += thrustPower * thrustHorizontal;
        shipMoveY += thrustPower * thrustVertical;
    }
    else if (downArrow)
    {
        shipMoveX -= thrustPower * thrustHorizontal;
        shipMoveY -= thrustPower * thrustVertical;
    }
    if (!upArrow && !downArrow)
    {
        shipMoveX *= decay;
        shipMoveY *= decay;
    }

    speed = Math.sqrt((shipMoveX * shipMoveX) + (shipMoveY * shipMoveY));
    if (speed > maxSpeed)
    {
        shipMoveX *= maxSpeed / speed;
        shipMoveY *= maxSpeed / speed;
    }

    ship.x += shipMoveX;
    ship.y -= shipMoveY;
}
```

As you can see, there is this new if-block:

```
if (!upArrow && !downArrow)
{
shipMoveX *= decay;
shipMoveY *= decay;
}
```

Here we're handling the case, if the player neither pressed up nor down and multiply
the spaceships horizontal/vertical speed by **decay**. If you scroll back a bit, you notice
it's value is *0.97*.
You can generally say, if you multiply a positive number x by 0 < y < 1, x will become smaller.

So if you're spaship is currently moving horizontally at 3 pixels per frame (shipMoveX=3 ; shipMoveY=0)
it will become 2.91 the next frame. The next frame it will be 2.8227, then 2.738019 ... and so on before it will finally reach zero in infinity.

Comment: As a better approach with fixed space, use absolute friction: `if (Math.abs(shipMoveX)<friction) shipMoveX=0; else if (shipmoveX>0) shipMoveX-=friction; else shipMoveX+=friction;` (add braces to taste)